# One translating Problem?

Tags: american-english, british-english, translation, books

What Does the following sentence mean?

> the BIU Fetches a new instruction whenever the queue has room for 2 bytes in the 6-byte 8086 queue, and for 1 byte in 4-byte 8088 queue

I thinks it means queue in 8086 has 3 room each of size 2 byte

am I right? any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. *Room* here is not like "a room", but an uncountable noun meaning "available space".

The 8086 queue has room/space for 6 bytes, and as soon as 2 or more of them are free, the BIU fetches a new instruction.